# fread return value 1 byte, even though file is getting read completely

Tags: c, file-io

I'm reading in a tarfile like this:

```
fh = fopen(filename, "r");

if (fh == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to open %s.\n", filename);
    printf("Exiting.\n");
    return 1;
}

fseek(fh, 0L, SEEK_END);
filesize = ftell(fh);
fseek(fh, 0L, SEEK_SET);

filecontents = (char*)malloc(filesize + 1);     // +1 for null terminator

byteCount = fread(filecontents, filesize, 1, fh);
filecontents[filesize] = 0; 

fclose(fh);

if (byteCount != filesize) {
    printf("Error reading %s.\n", filename);
    printf("Expected filesize: %ld bytes.\n", filesize);
    printf("Bytes read: %d bytes.\n", byteCount);
}
```

I then proceed to decode the contents of the tarfile and extract the files stored within. Everything works correctly, and the files get extracted just fine, yet `fread()` is returning `1` instead of `filesize`. The output I get is:

```
Error reading readme.tar.
Expected filesize: 10240 bytes.
Bytes read: 1 bytes.
```

According to [CPP Reference on `fread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/), the return value should be the number of bytes read.

Comment: Read that page again... "*The total number of **elements** successfully read is returned.*"

Comment: But since, in my case, each element is 1 byte, shouldn't it be the same as number of bytes read?

Comment: Your element is `filesize`

Comment: i think since you read the hole file in `one` step, the number of elements red is also `one`

Comment: It's `size,count`, not `count,size`. So you're reading 1 element with the size `filesize`.

Comment: According to the function signature, you're asking it to read *one* element whose size is `filesize` bytes. The function does just that and returns the fact that it succeeded in reading *one* element.

Comment: Change your call to be `fread(filecontents, 1, filesize, fh);` It is literally that simple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
//byteCount = fread(filecontents, filesize, 1, fh);
byteCount = fread(filecontents, 1, filesize, fh);
```

Comment: won't that queue `filesize` reads of one byte, which will actually be translated to some multiple of a sector size `filesize * sectorsize`?